# Problema com comparação de datas em Javascript

Tags: javascript, data, comparação, momentjs

Tenho uma função em Javascript que é para verificar se a "data_atual" é maior que a "data_validade". Se for maior, é para exibir na tela o texto "Expirado", se não, mantém o texto "Válido".

**Qual o problema?**
A função está considerando apenas o **dia** da data de validade, **e não o mês e o ano**. Caso o dia da validade seja maior que o dia atual, ele exibe "Válido", mesmo que o ano da validade seja 2010 por exemplo. Acredito que o problema possa ter alguma relação por a validade estar no formato de texto, no banco de dados como Varchar.

**Segue um exemplo do código: https://jsfiddle.net/ec0nugyq/**

```js
var data_validade = '20/03/2010'; // Simula a data de validade do banco de dados (VARCHAR)
var data_atual = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // Captura a data atual no formato brasileiro - Ex: 14/03/2021

if (data_atual > data_validade) {
document.write('Expirado'); // Se a data atual for maior que a validade, exibe Expirado na tela
} else {
document.write('Válido'); // Se a data atual for maior que a validade, exibe Válido na tela
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Caso alguém saiba como solucionar isso de uma forma simples, agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deve ser observado que a biblioteca *Moment.js* em sua
> [documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) desencoraja aos desenvolvedores a incluírem o
> *Moment.js* em novos projetos.
> Na documentação da biblioteca são alegados as razões para tal.

Quanto ao problema da questão esse pode ser facilmente resolvido usando o objeto *JavaScript* nativo [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
//Prepara a data para ser usada como argumento do constructo Date.
let data = '20/03/2010'.split("/").reverse();    //Separa os componentes da data e os coloca na ordem ano, mês e dia para ser consumida pelo constructor Date(ano, mês, dia).
data[1]--;                                       //Reduz em uma unidade o mês pois o constructor Date trabalha com meses de 0 até 11 onde mês 0 é janeiro.

let data_validade = new Date(...data);
let data_atual = new Date();

if (data_atual > data_validade) {
  document.write('Expirado');
} else {
  document.write('Válido');
}
```

O principal problema do seu código é que em:

```
if (data_atual > data_validade)
```

Você está comparando duas strings pois em momento algum `data_atual` foi convertido para um objeto que modele tempo/datas e `data_validade` é a representação string da data atual obtida com `moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');`. Então sua comparação faz apenas a comparação dentre os caracteres das duas strings e não de datas em si.

Para corrigir o problema bastava trabalhar apenas com objetos `Date`.
Para converter a string `20/03/2010` em uma forma consumível pelo constructor [`new Date(ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#syntax) a string foi quebrada em seus componentes usando o método [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) que divide uma [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) em uma lista ordenada de sub-strings e as retorna em um [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `[dia, mês, ano]` e então invertida com o método [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) para que o formato seja consumido pelo constructor `new Date(ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo);`. Em seguida o mês sofreu um decremento de uma unidade pois o constructor de datas opera com o mês começando com 0 para Janeiro até 11 para Dezembro.
Isso para que o array contendo a data possa ser consumido pelo constructor `new Date(ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo);` usando a [sintaxe de espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) utilizando apenas os três primeiros parâmetros.
Fora o mencionado o restante do código permanece o mesmo.

Para facilitar o uso pode ser criada uma função que converte a string no formato `dd/mm/YYY` em um objeto `Date` aqui chamada `ptBRStringToDate(s)` onde `s` é uma string contendo a data.

```js
function ptBRStringToDate(s) {
  let data = s.split("/").reverse();
  data[1]--;
  return new Date(...data);
}

let listaDatas = ["10/03/2020", "10/03/2021", "10/03/2022"]
let data_atual = new Date();

for (let d of listaDatas) {
  let data_validade = ptBRStringToDate(d);
  document.write(`${d}: ${(data_atual > data_validade)? 'Expirado':'Válido'}<br>`);
}
```

Comment: Olá Augusto Vasques, agradeço pela sua resposta! Sou iniciante em programação, mas entendi o problema agora com sua explicação, consegui solucionar o problema ainda utilizando o MomentJS com o isAfter que é uma solução "fácil", mas confesso que irei tentar fazer dessa forma que você mencionou, justamente devido o comunicado do Moment em evitar utilizar em novos projetos. Valeu!

Comment: @Gabriel-SkyGR, Caso o interesse e se adeque ao seu projeto no comunicado eles fazem sugestões de outras libs para substituir o MomentJS.

Comment: Perfeito, irei dar uma olhada, obrigado!

Comment: Quando o `Temporal` chegar, vai ser tão lindo :)

Comment: @CmteCardeal mas esse é o substantivo que significa chuva forte eu usei o adjetivo comum de dois gêneros relativo a tempo cronológico.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var data_validade  = new Date('03/20/2021')     //dia expirado -> mm/dd/yyyy

    var data_atual = new Date();                    //tirando o dia de hj

    if (data_atual > data_validade) {           //comparando ambos em segundos
    document.write('Expirado'); // Se a data atual for maior que a validade, exibe Expirado na tela
    } else {
    document.write('Válido'); // Se a data atual for maior que a validade, exibe Válido na tela
    }
```

Eu consegui desse jeito :) Tem cuidado com a string pois o formato é "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: Olá @IndexError, agradeço pela resposta, o código realmente funciona no JSFiddle, mas ao implementá-lo em meu projeto não responde conforme esperado, ainda assim considera apenas o dia. Já tentei usar o MomentJS, tentei usar o Javascript puro com new Date(), mudei no banco de dados as datas de VARCHAR para DATE, mas ainda não consegui que identifique quando o mês ou o ano da validade é anterior da data atual.

Comment: achei meu código mais simples e limpo kkk'